# Wordpress error?

Tags: wordpress

I encountered the problem this morning in my blog

404 Not Found

The server can not find the requested page:

```
www.statz-counter.info/wp_global_footer.php?random=____YTo2OntpOjA7czo5OiJibGl4ZWQtMTAiO2k6MTtpOjI0MDA7aToyO3M6MTU6Ind3dy5hemFtLm9yZy5teSI7aTozO3M6MTU6Ii9ibG9nL0luZGV4LnBocCI7aTo0O3M6MzU6Ik1vemlsbGFXaW5kb3dzVU5UZW5VU3J2R2Vja29GaXJlZm94IjtpOjU7czo1OiJlbi11cyI7fQ== (port 80)
```

Please forward this error screen to www.statz-counter.info's WebMaster.

What's causing the error actually? Any idea?

Comment: Is `www.statz-counter.info` your site? It seems to be reset to the default cPanel Installation...

Answer (score 3):

You got hacked.

- http://www.securityfocus.com/brief/1008
- http://wordpress.org/development/2009/09/keep-wordpress-secure/

Comment: yah..i suspected my blog got hacked. I tried to google for solution but found a lot of sites were hacked with the same message. Is by upgrading the wordpress
 version will actually fixed the problem?

Comment: Most sane system admins will not trust a server or application after it has been hacked. I would at minimum completely remove all files from the web server, and delete the database. Then start from scratch. You may want to export your database to separate SQL files that can be audited and imported on a piecemeal database. You can't just blindly re-import since an attacker could have left a back door.

Answer (score 1):

From WP: Hack Warning, Upgrade Immediately (with instructions to clean and upgrade) http://wordpress.org/support/topic/307660?replies=1